# javascript click game using less html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic javascript game where you need to click multiple images in a certain period of time.  (currently 4 seconds)

My javascript looks like this

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", countdown);
function countdown() {
setTimeout(function(){ 
prompt("you got" + counter);   
}, 4000);

}

var counter = 0;
function countup() {
counter = counter + 1;
}
```

And while that does work, every img in my HTML has to have:

```
onclick="countup(); this.onclick=null"
```

which after 20 pictures is a lot.  My question is, is there a way to condense this?  Some js method of collecting all the pictures by class and applying the click countup and null to it?

Comment: You can use `addEventListener` to bind to an element's click event.  Just like you already do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to select all your images and add an event listener to count up and remove the event listener like so:

```
function handleClick(e)
{
    countup();
    e.target.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll('img'); 
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) 
{
    images[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}
```

More about `document.querySelectorAll` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

You can also use a classname with querySelectorAll, pass in '.myClass'

Answer (score -1):

Yes - use `getElementsByClassName`. E.g. if you apply the class 'button' to all of your button images:

```
var buttons = document.getElementByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', countup);
}
```

To remove the event listener after the first click requires something a bit more complicated, however. For example, you can write a second function that adds an event listener which calls your original function and then removes itself.

```
var buttons = document.getElementByClassName('button');

function clickOnce(el, func) {
    function listener() {
        func();
        el.removeEventListener('click', listener);
    }
    el.addEventListener('click', listener);
}
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    clickOnce(buttons[i], countup);
}
```

Comment: This can be done in a more simple way. And the question is not about clicking on buttons, but clicking on images.

Comment: This answer is not about clicking on buttons, but elements with the class 'button' as in the question.